# Scraping images with Wikipedia API does not work all the time

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, wikipedia, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to scrape the first image of Wikipedia pages of companies. (Quite often it's a logo.)

This works sometimes:

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
title = "Microsoft"

# Set parameters for the API request
params = {
"action": "query",
"format": "json",
"formatversion": 2,
"prop": "pageimages",
"piprop": "original",
"titles": title,
}

response = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params=params)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

But for other companies, let's say Binance or Coinbase, it does not work. I'm not able to figure out why.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?

Comment: It does not return any image

Comment: How do you know that? All you got is a JSON data structure.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see it documented anywhere, but I suspect that pageimages does not include .svg which is the only image file in the Coinbase article. Using images instead works fine:

```
import requests

API_ENDPOINT = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php"
title = "Coinbase"

# Set parameters for the API request
params = {
"action": "query",
"format": "json",
"formatversion": 2,
"prop": "images",
"titles": title,
"imlimit":1
}

response = requests.get(API_ENDPOINT, params=params)
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Returns:

```
{'continue': {'imcontinue': '39596725|Commons-logo.svg', 'continue': '||'}, 'query': {'pages': [{'pageid': 39596725, 'ns': 0, 'title': 'Coinbase', 'images': [{'ns': 6, 'title': 'File:Coinbase.svg'}]}]}}
```